# How to query foreign key in Django with if conditions and do something if a condition is met

Tags: django, filter, tuples

I'm working a website where I want to display product that are of two categories which are premium and free package and I want to filter all the premium package and label it with a star or a premium text to indicate it a premium package and for the free I'll do nothing. I don't know if I should user foreign key for this or tuple.

models.py:

```py
STATUS_CHOICE = (
    ('draft', 'Draft'),
    ('in_review', 'In Review'),
    ('published', 'Published')
)

class Package_Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10000, verbose_name="Title")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=1000, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("package-categories", args=[self.slug])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
        
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Package Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Package Categories"

class Vectors(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Title")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="vectors-images/%Y/%m/%d/", default="default.jpg", verbose_name="Image Cover")
    vec_file = models.FileField(upload_to='vector-uploads/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Upload File")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Category")
    package_category = models.ForeignKey(Package_Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Package Category")
    tags = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Tag")
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICE, default="published", max_length=150, verbose_name='Status')
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Creator")
    creator_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="creators-images/%Y/%m/%d/", default="default.jpg", verbose_name="Creator Image")
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Created")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Vector"
        verbose_name_plural = "Vectors"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("vector-details", args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

index.html:

```html
{% for vector in vectors %}
                    <!-- Single Pricing Box -->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="_45lio">
                            <div class="_jk58o item_image_urip">
                                <a href="#" class="_5gt9"><img src="{{vector.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" alt=""></a>
                                
                                <a href="item-detail.html" class="urip_link download"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
                                <div class="image_urip_caption">
                                    <div class="urip_caption_flex">
                                        <div class="urip_author">
                                            <div class="urip_avater">
                                                <a href="author-detail.html.html" class="author-img">
                                                    <img src="assets/img/author.png" class="img-fluid" alt="" />
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="urip_avater_place">
                                                <h3 class="urip_title"><a href="author-detail.html.html">Adam vilson</a></h3>
                                                <span>Liverpool, London</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="urip_caption_last">
                                        <div class="item_list_links">
                                            <a href="premium-stock-detail.html" class="urip_link"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                                            <a href="premium-stock-detail.html" class="urip_link"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="_io980 item_image_urip">
                                    {% if package_category.premium %}
                                        <h1>Premium Package</h1>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <h1>Free Package</h1>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <h4 class="_95lp"><a href="#" class="_50gt">{{vector.package_category}}</a></h4>

                                    <span class="_ip76n">{{vector.category}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Vectors, Tag, Category, Package_Category

def index(request):
    vectors = Vectors.objects.filter(status='published').order_by('-created')

    context = {
        'vectors': vectors,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do something like this if you are not using drf just by using the same model.

```
def index(request):
    vectors = Vectors.objects.filter(status='published', package_category__title =="premimum").order_by('-created')

     if vectors.exists():

        // do something:
     

    context = {
        'vectors': vectors,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Although the best option would be to use serializers with drf